# Registration fails - No email is sent to me

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I tried to merge this account with my previous, unregistered one. So I clicked on the link to recover my account and entered my email address. But I haven't received an email yet. I tried to register that account a few days ago, but that didn't work either.
It seems that I just don't get any emails by stackoverflow. My spam folder is empty, I checked that. What can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two emails were sent to you... Regarding your newer, registered account. Unfortunately when you have two accounts with the same email, using the recovery tool tends to be a bit of a crap-shoot.

I've merged your accounts manually, so you should be set now.